# Reverse deadblow hammer?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, kinematics, vibrations

Exploring the benefits of deadblow hammer physics in sports.

I play badminton, and have developed elbow pain that is aggravated whenever I smash (overhead forehand, like a tennis serve). This is caused by vibration transmitted through the racket, into my wrist, where it “jerks” on tendons connected to the elbow.

I’ve added some cushioning under my grip-tape to dampen the shock from the racket, and I wear an elbow brace to help absorb the force. This has helped, but I still feel pain after games where I smashed a lot.

From what I’ve read, deadblow hammers dissipate force by allowing the contents of its head to jump around and ricochet off each other. Kind of like how water behaves when you drop a bottle on the floor.

If I turned my racket into a REVERSE deadblow hammer, by adding sand or pellets into the HANDLE, would that help me?
Why isn’t this considered in designing other impact tools?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but probably not practical, for the following reasons.

A near as I can tell, a light racket has the advantage that it can be wielded swiftly (low inertia) and swung up to high speed (for a good smash). Adding for example lead shot in a hollow handle will greatly increase the inertia of the racket, making it difficult to quickly maneuver into position for a return or a save.

Here is something else to consider which may help.

In mechanical engineering parlance there is something called the *center of percussion* of a rigid body where, if you swing that body to hit something with it, the reaction force that shocks your arm is minimized if you hit it at the center of percussion.

The region immediately surrounding the C. of P. is sometimes called the "sweet spot" and sports equipment designers strive to design bats, rackets, etc. so as to maximize the area encompassing the sweet spot.

It sounds as if your return strikes are outside the badminton racket's sweet spot and your arm is suffering because of it. I would look into different rackets with the assistance of  a knowledgeable coach or instructor to see if there's one with a sweet spot that better suits your style.